# C#, foreach values to TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

From below given foreach loop I'm getting all the file names in a folder. I want to know how to put all the file names in text box. According to below code only the last file name appear in textbox.

```
private void btnGetFileNames_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      DirectoryInfo dinf = new DirectoryInfo(tbxFileLocation.Text);

      foreach (FileInfo Fi in dinf.GetFiles())
        {
            tbxFileList.Text=Fi.ToString();  
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's because you are overwriting with the latest file name in each iteration. How do you want to show all the names? As a comma separated list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and append the filenames to it, Display finally

```
StringBuilder filenames = new StringBuilder();
foreach (FileInfo Fi in dinf.GetFiles())
  {
      filenames.Append(Fi.ToString());
      filenames.Append(",");           
   }
tbxFileList.Text=filenames.ToString();
```

Comment: Could one not more simply do something like this `var files = string.Join(", ", directoryInfo.GetFiles().Select(i => i.Name));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private void btnGetFileNames_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DirectoryInfo dinf = new DirectoryInfo(tbxFileLocation.Text);

  foreach (FileInfo Fi in dinf.GetFiles())
    {
        tbxFileList.Text+=Fi.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you both of you for your time. It's really helpful.